# My code fails at a certain point. Java File IO

Tags: java, file-io

I am new to Java. I programmed in C++. I am trying to work with files but my code fails when I try create a file, that is, when the program tests if the file exists, it fails, but I have already created the file.

```
public Schedule(String name, String event)
{
   String filename= name+event+".txt";
   File TimeTable=new File(filename);
   if (TimeTable.exists()&&TimeTable.isFile()){ 
      writeToFile(TimeTable,name,event,filename);
      System.out.println("In constructor");
   }//fails here

}
```

Comment: I dont think that TimeTable is a Java class otherwise Java wouldn't let me compile.

Comment: Try to explain more what you mean by "fails" when you write a question. Does it not do what you expected? Explain what happened and what you were expecting.

Comment: It's highlighted as a class name because the convention is for classes to start with a CapitalLetter, and variables to start with a lowercaseLetter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have already created the file

If the following line is the reason you are saying this, then you're wrong.

`File TimeTable=new File(filename);`

This is making an abstract representation of file/directory pathnames but will not make the file if it doesn't exist.

`File TimeTable=new File(filename);
 TimeTable.createNewFile();`

The `createNewFile` method will make the physical file if it doesn't already exist.